# Importing data from online my sql data base to the attribute table in arcgis 10.2

Tags: arcgis-10.2, attribute-table, file-geodatabase, import, online

I have point features in ArcGIS which have sewer manholes plotted on them along with latitude and longitude. The attributes of these manholes are stored in an online server using MySQL database.

Can I import the attribute data into ArcGIS and merge it with the point data (spatial data)?

Data is in .gdf fomat

The join option does not help my purpose.

Does ArcGIS have an built in feature or will I have to write a script to do so?

Comment: Please explain why joining didn't help